# Docker tag error "No such image" in Github Actions

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

Im trying out Github actions to automate my docker build and push to GCP Artifact Registry. But my Github actions got an error "No such image" on docker tag command.

**Below is the yaml file for Github Actions : **

```
name: Build and Push Docker Image to Google Cloud Platform
on: 
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  build-push-gcr:
    name: Build and Push to GCP
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      IMAGE_NAME: <my-image-name>
      PROJECT_ID: <my-project-id>
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0
      with: 
        service_account_key: ${{ secrets.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY }}
        project_id: ${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}
        export_default_credentials: true

    - name: Build Docker Image
      run: docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t carro-backend-api:latest .

    - name: Configure Docker Client
      run: |-
        gcloud auth configure-docker --quiet
        gcloud auth configure-docker us-central1-docker.pkg.dev --quiet

    - name: Push Docker Image to Container Registry (GCR)
      run: |-
        docker tag $IMAGE_NAME:latest gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME:latest
        docker push gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME:latest

    - name: Push Docker Image to Artifact Registry
      run: |-
        docker tag $IMAGE_NAME:latest us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME/$IMAGE_NAME:latest
        docker push us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME/$IMAGE_NAME:latest
```

This is the error showing in the Github action.
[Error screenshot at Github Actions]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqx4n.png

I had found some thread saying its the "buildx" issue, and I tried the solution provided. But its still the same. Do I miss out something?

Where is the build located after the build run successfully on Github Actions?

My first time trying out Github Actions to automate things, so not so sure if I missed out something.

Comment: Propably your `$IMAGE_NAME` is not `carro-backend-api`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to retag the image, especially when you are inconsistent with the values. Instead output the build directly to your desired image name:

```yaml
      run: docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME:latest" -t "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME/$IMAGE_NAME:latest" --push .
```

Perform your registry auth before this step and you can delete the tag and push steps.

Comment: I'd also recommend using Docker's build-push-action instead of calling buildx manually: https://github.com/docker/build-push-action